# Having trouble with "selected" navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this simple horizontal navigation menu to work but when I go and add an "active" class to the active li, nothing is changing. the .active just doesn't show up? What did I do wrong guys?

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Referral</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reseller</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    #nav ul{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:40px auto;
        padding:0;
        width:625px;
        height:50px;
    }
#nav li{
display:inline;
    }
    #nav li a,
    #nav li a:visited,
    #nav li a:link {
        width:120px;
        height:20px;
        display:inline;
        float:left;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top:5px;  
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        margin-top:auto;
        margin-bottom:auto;
        font-family: arial;
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#929292;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
        margin-left:5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    #nav li a{

    }
    #nav li a:hover{
        color: #ffffff;  
        cursor: pointer;  
        background-color: #2F5290;
    }
    #nav li a:active{
        color: #FAAF31;  
    }
    .active{
        background-color: #2F5290;
        color: #FAAF31;  
    }
```

Comment: Your issue is one of specificity. `#nav li a` is worth 102 points of specificity, but `.active` is only worth 10 points. If you update it to `#nav li.active a` you will get 112 points, thus having enough specificity to override your original styles. You can read more about [specificity on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity) **Also**, you are applying `background-color` and `color` to the `a` but only applying it to the `li` on `.active`.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, that did the trick. I've been trying to learn on my own and haven't come across specificity. Thanks for the lesson setek!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specificity is your problem. In quick terms: ids are worth 100, classes worth 10 and elements worth 1, so #nav li a is worth 102 points of specificity, but .active is only worth 10 points. If you update it to #nav li a.active you will get 112 points, thus having enough specificity to override your original styles. You can read more about [specificity on W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)

Thanks @setek for the good answer, I thought that it should really be the answer and added a bit as well.